# A conjecture related to Bézout’s identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisibility

**Notation.** If $n$ is an integer, $p$ is a prime, and $k$ is the unique nonnegative integer such that $p^k \mid n$ and $p^{k+1} \nmid n$, then we write $v_p(n)=k$.

I’m wondering about the following claim, which is evidently related to Bézout’s identity.

> **Conjecture.**
> Let $x$ and $y$ be positive integers such that $g := \gcd(x,y) > 1$, and assume at least one prime $\phi \mid g$ such that $v_\phi(x)=v_\phi(g)$. Then there exist nonzero integers $a$ and $b$, with $\phi \nmid ab\bigl((2a)^2+b^2\bigr)$ such that $v_\phi(ax+by)>v_\phi(x)$.

Is this known? Is it either trivially true or trivially false? If it’s not trivially either, any hints on how to prove it, or excellent references on related results, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @GregMartin: Why does it imply that? Numerical evidence doesn’t suggest that. For example, let $x=442=(2)(13)(17)$ and $y=455=(5)(7)(13)$, so $g=13$ and $v_{13}(x)=v_{13}(y)=v_{13}(g)=1$. Now $5x-3y=845=(5)(13^2)$, so $v_{13}(5x-3y)>v_{13}(x)$.

Comment: if $v_{\phi}(x)\lt v_{\phi}(y)$, then since $\phi$ cannot divide $a$ then the largest power of $\phi$ that can divide $ax+by$ is exactly $v_{\phi}(x)$: just factor it out and notice that $by$ is a multiple of $\phi$ but $ax/\phi^k$ is not, when $k=v_{\phi}(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, if it happens that $v_\phi(y)>v_\phi(x)$, then the conjecture is false because $v_\phi(ax+by)=v_\phi(x)$ for every $a$ that's not a multiple of $\phi$. So one needs the additional hypothesis $v_\phi(y)=v_\phi(x)$ at least.

However, the conjecture is still false even with that additional hypothesis. For example, take $x=y=5$; then $v_5(ax+by) = 1+v_5(a+b)$ exceeds $1=v_5(x)$ if and only if $b\equiv-a\pmod5$; however, this implies that $(2a)^2+b^2\equiv 4a^2+(-a)^2\equiv5a^2\equiv0\pmod5$, so that $5\mid\big((2a)^2+b^2\big)$ contrary to the conjecture. Similar counterexamples can be constructed for any prime $\phi$ congruent to $1\pmod4$ (we take $x=v\phi$ and $y=w\phi$ where $(vw^{-1})^2\equiv-4\pmod\phi$).

Comment: Is there any restricted version of the conjecture that might be true? For example, if $x$ and $y$ are distinct, and $v_\phi(x)=v_\phi(y)$?

Comment: In the example I gave, above, $x=442$ and $y=455$, and $\phi = 13$ (which is congruent to 1 modulo 4), and yet $13^2 \mid 845 = 5x-3y$. What makes that special?

Comment: Why is that a special example? It's not in question that sometimes $v_\phi(ax+by)$ can be larger than $v_\phi(x)$ (indeed, it reduces to simply a linear equation over a field). As for your earlier comment, the distinctness of $x$ and $y$ isn't important—it's the residue class of $vw^{-1}\pmod\phi$ that's important.

Comment: By “special”, I meant that it’s not a counterexample, even though you wrote that counterexamples “can be constructed for any prime $\phi$ congruent to 1 (mod 4)”.  In any case, I’m gathering that with the correct constraint on the residue class of $vw^{-1}$, a conjecture which _is_ true can be found. Thanks!